# SQL server replication, and existing data

Tags: sql, sql-server, replication

If I have database A, and database B. Database B has existing data... Database A is empty.

If I turn on replication, with Database A being the publisher, and Database B being the subscriber ... will the exisiting data within Database B be deleted? Or will the data remain in Database B, and any new data added to Database A be replicated to B.

I'm thinking when you create the replication, the entire database B would be overwritten with database A data.

Is that right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my experience, a subscriber will obtain the new data from the publisher. You will not be able to create a subscriber and simply append to database B. You may need to consider a different process. The Merge keyword could be an option. [merge (MSDN)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

Comment: Merge is not a reasonable option to use instead of replication, and we can not just assume the databases A and B are on same sql server instance as merge will requires that.

Answer (score 2):

when registering B as a suscriber to publication P based on dabatase A (P can be a subgroup of A, with filters, limitation on tables, etc), a snapshot of A, containing needed database structure and data, will be used to recreate B. Thus original B database and its data will be deleted.